# PHP's cURL URL is being automatically entered in the browser's address bar

Tags: php, curl

I have this code :

```
private function sendToInfusionsoft($xid, $form_name, $firstname, $lastname, $email)
{                       
    $url = "https://company-name.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/{$xid}";

    $params = [
            'inf_form_xid'=>$xid,
            'inf_form_name'=>$form_name,
            'infusionsoft_version'=>'1.62.0.45',
            'inf_field_FirstName'=>$firstname,
            'inf_field_LastName'=>$lastname,
            'inf_field_Email'=>$email
            ];               
    $params = http_build_query($params);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

But when I run it in the browser, the browser's URL is actually redirecting to https://company-name.infusionsoft.com/etc-etc

How is this not running in the background ? Why is this picking up in the address bar ? For this reason , it's not redirecting to my website URL.

Comment: I think the server is redirecting

Comment: cURL will just echo the content of the page to the browser. If that page redirects or runs a script with `window.location.replace` then the address bar will change because it will execute whatever the remote page contains.

Comment: use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to prevent curl of automatically print the output to your browser.

Comment: Thanks hassan - you should put this as your answer - I'll accept.